# I want to ask the meaning of this words 痛い女

Tags: slang, phrases

I tried to look at it dictionary but I can't get the real meaning behind it. What does 痛い女 mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the definition [here](https://bosesound.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-417.html).
The usage can be considered "slang" because you won't find this meaning in a dictionary.

> イタいとは、非常識な言動をする人に対して不憫、みじめに思うこと。
>   KYな発言をしたり、変な格好をしたり、当人は気づかずにイタいことをしている場合が多い。
>   当初はネットスラングだったが、今では一般に浸透している。

Translation:

イタイ is used to describe a person that is behavior is lacking common sense, and you pity or look down upon them. They make KY (空気{くうき}が読めない{よめない}) remarks or dress oddly, and do things that are "いたい" without realizing it. Originally was net slang but is now more commonly used in general public.

Also, perhaps a couple examples would help:

1. Some people may consider a woman who calls themselves by their own name as 痛い女 because it sounds childish (however, often times there person themselves doesn't realize this).
2. A women that dresses very inappropriately. For example, a mother who goes to a school event but dresses in revealing clothes.

Comment: Sounds like the modern usage of "cringe(y)" in English.

Answer (score 0):

I think how the 「イタい」 being used is basically explained in a gender neutral situation by the other answer. However, if she is saying to herself as 痛{いた}い女{おんな}, she is feeling pitiful or pathetic since she can't forget her ex-lover or something.

We need some more information to know her real feeling about if she may want to get over such a miserable situation or simply be resenting something.